# PowerShell Invoke-Sqlcmd with Array item as variable in WHERE

Tags: arrays, t-sql, variables, powershell, sqlcmd

I'm not getting any output from this script. Not even an error msg... I think my problem is the use of a variable in the WHERE clause. I've tried escaping this $(item) with backtics but making no progress. Can anyone help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

```
$dbserver   = "AHDC389"
$dbase  = "FOO"
$table  = "$($dbase).dbo.BAR"

Import-Module “sqlps” -DisableNameChecking

$myArray    = @(Invoke-Sqlcmd "Select myColumn From adifferentserver.dbo.[mylookuptable]") | select-object -expand myColumn

ForEach ($item in $myyArray) {

    Invoke-Sqlcmd "Select * FROM $table Where FacilityID='$(item)' "

}
```

UPDATE:

So when I modify the script like below, is seems the variable for the Where= is not expanding out.

```
$dbserver   = "AHDC389"
$dbase  = "FOO"
$table  = "$($dbase).dbo.BAR"

Import-Module “sqlps” -DisableNameChecking

$myArray    = @(Invoke-Sqlcmd "Select myColumn From adifferentserver.dbo.[mylookuptable]") | select-object -expand myColumn

$myQuery    = "Select * FROM {0} Where FacilityID='{1}'" -f $table, $item

ForEach ($item in $mArray) {

    Write-Host $myQuery
    #Invoke-Sqlcmd $myQuery

}
```

The value of $myQuery is returned to the console indicating the $item is not being expanded:

```
Select * FROM  FOO.dbo.BAR Where Facility=''
```

Comment: If you build the string outside the loop then $item is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simply personal preference, but I build the string using the -format operator:

```
$cmdStr = 'Select * FROM {0} WHERE FacilityID={1}' -f $table, $item
Write-Host 'Executing: ' + $cmdStr
Invoke-Sqlcmd $cmdStr
```

Comment: I still get no output to the console when I do this. I suspect he problem is the need for TSQL to use the ' in the WHERE='foo' clause.

Comment: You built the string outside of the loop.

Comment: @ColinA.White Don't, because you're not.  We've all facepalmed

Answer (score 0):

`$item` is not defined until the `ForEach` loop so it cannot be used in the assignment prior to that. Move the declaration into the loop.

```
ForEach ($item in $mArray) {
$myQuery    = "Select * FROM {0} Where FacilityID='{1}'" -f $table, $item

Write-Host $myQuery
#Invoke-Sqlcmd $myQuery

}
```

Comment: Just seen that @EBGreen answered as I typing.